# Boto3 set custom user agent to test S3 access policies

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I am using boto3 to create some tests to verify microservice access policies on an S3 bucket.

Bucket setup:

```js
test-bucket/
  service/
    micro-a/
    micro-b/
```

This bucket policy is meant to limit access to those with the role specified:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessIfInThisRole",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "*role-id*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The role id is referencing this IAM role which grants access to each microservice specific folder in the bucket, based on the microservice user agent, ie microservice A's user agent might be 'micro-a' and so should have access to `test-bucket/service/micro-a/*` but not to `test-bucket/service/micro-b/*`:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::as-bucket-test/service/${aws:useragent}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::as-bucket-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "service/${aws:useragent}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand how to create the boto3 client so that I can set the user-agent multiple items to verify different access policies. This is what I have so far:

```
import boto3
import botocore

session = botocore.session.Session(
    user_agent_name="something"
)

session = boto3.session.Session(botocore_session=session)
print session
```

Resulting in:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user_agent_name'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S3 client takes a config object where you can set custom config options including setting a custom user agent

```
from boto3 import client
import botocore

# Create a config
session_config = botocore.config.Config(
  user_agent="new_user_agent"
)

s3 = client(
  's3',
  config=session_config
)

# Make an API call
response = s3.put_object(
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *append* to the default user agent, rather than replace it entirely, use this:

```
import botocore.config

session_config = botocore.config.Config(
    ...
    user_agent_extra="myapp/1.2.3",
)
```

You will get a `User-Agent` header with all the original context too, something like:

```
Boto3/1.24.67 Python/3.9.13 Botocore/1.27.67 myapp/1.2.3
```